# "failed to write automation extension zip" Error comes when I run my code after creating a Jar, It works in Eclipse IDE. But doesn't work as a Jar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, chrome

Chrome version : 75.0.3770.100

> C:\Users\ramkrishna.bhandare\Documents\StressTestExamination\OES
>   Project>Title SeleniumExam.

```
C:\Users\ramkrishna.bhandare\Documents\StressTestExamination\OES Project>java -j
ar ".\Ramkrishna-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs
/branch-heads/3770@{#40}) on port 22106
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent
 access by malicious code.
Exception is caught
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: failed to write automatio
n extension zip
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17
:03'
System info: host: 'CSS-D-060', ip: '10.10.10.218', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.a
rch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00C47DF3+1474035]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BC07D1+919505]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B5CB43+510787]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF089E+67742]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AEDF37+57143]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B10CE4+199908]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B1069D+198301]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B0EECB+192203]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF5FF6+90102]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF765A+95834]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AF7554+95572]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DA231C+1249612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CF1575+525221]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CF1310+524608]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C55D28+1531176]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CF1D4A+527226]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BD75F6+1013238]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BD746F+1012847]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BE365B+1062491]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BE379F+1062815]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BE2745+1058629]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74F97C04+36]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x774BAD8F+143]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x774BAD5A+90]


C:\Users\ramkrishna.bhandare\Documents\StressTestExamination\OES Project>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Check for Hub/Node Port configuration is correct or not.

Comment: Please tell me how it is to be done. Thanks

Comment: Please check ur framework has any Hub/Node configuration. In that go to the particular folder by explorer and open node file by notepad. Then verify the port configuration correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the kaspersky antivirus solved the problem for me.

Now the Jar is executing as expected.

I guess I would need to add exception in the antivirus.